# Retain the selected data after submit Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-blade, dropdown, retain

Is there a way to retain the selected data after submit?

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{trans('words.shows_text')}}*</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="form-control select2" name="series" id="episode_series_id">
                                <option value="">{{trans('words.select_show')}}</option>
                                @foreach($series_list as $series_data)
                                  <option value="{{$series_data->id}}" @if(isset($episode_info->id) && $series_data->id==$episode_info->episode_series_id) selected @endif>{{$series_data->series_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

Here is the controller

```
$episode_obj->save();
         
        
        if(!empty($inputs['id'])){

            \Session::flash('flash_message', trans('words.successfully_updated'));

            return \Redirect::back();
        }else{

            \Session::flash('flash_message', trans('words.added'));

            return \Redirect::back()->withInput();
```

I tried some old() function, but I must be doing it wrong.

```
 <option value="{{$series_data->id}}" @if(isset($episode_info->id) && $series_data->id==$episode_info->episode_series_id) @selected(old('series_data->id') == $episode_series_id) @endif>{{$series_data->series_name}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

`old()` function only works if you are using validations: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#repopulating-forms

On Controller

```php
$validator = Validator::make($inputs, [
    'id' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return \Redirect::back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
}

// do the things
```

On view:

```html
 <option value="{{$series_data->id}}" {{ in_array(old('id'), [$episode_info->id, $series_data->id]) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$series_data->series_name}}</option>
```

Comment: Yeah I already have validator i didnt include all of the code in the controller a above. The the on view: code you gave resulted in "Undefined variable $episode_info"

Comment: You can change ``$episode_info->id`` to ``$episode_info->id ?? null``